# Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove that a sum converges

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|^2$ converges where $(z_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of positive terms, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|z_n|}{n}$ must also converge. I have tried to do it using Cauchy-Schwarz, like so:

It is given that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|^2$ converges to some positive value $L$, and the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Therefore $(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|^2)(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2})$ converges to $\frac{L\pi^2}{6}$.

Using Cauchy-Schwarz, $(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|\frac{1}{n})^2 \leq (\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|^2)(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}) = \frac{L\pi^2}{6}$

Therefore $(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|\frac{1}{n}) \leq \sqrt{\frac{L\pi^2}{6}}$ so the sum converges.

I looked at the solution afterwards, and it gives quite a different proof involving bounds and partial sums. My proof is shorter which makes me think that I'm missing something important or I am incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

well it's not a 100% clear that Cauchy-Schwartz applies for your infinite sums.

The argument I would give is

$$
(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{K}|z_n|\frac{1}{n})^2 \leq (\sum\limits_{n=1}^{K}|z_n|^2)(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{K}\frac{1}{n^2}) 
$$

for any $K$ so

$$(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{K}|z_n|\frac{1}{n})^2 \leq (\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|^2)(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}) 
$$

So,

$$(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{K}|z_n|\frac{1}{n}) \leq (\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|^2)^{1/2}(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2})^{1/2}.
$$

So, the LHS is bounded and converges done.

Comment: What exactly do you think is not 100% clear in applying CS inequality to $\ell^2$ sequences?

Comment: it all comes down to what you are allowed to take as assumed and what you aren't...

Comment: I see. So the difference in your proof and that suggested in OP is that you assume CS for *finite* sequences while the OP needs more advanced version of CS for (the Hilbert space) $\ell^{2+}$. That answers the question why the suggested solution looked different - they did not want to assume too much.